# How to allow user to place markers on map?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, markers

I have this little question about markers. What should I do to let user place his own marker on my google maps based app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can do this. One of them is to add a marker when the user long presses on the map. To detect long presses, implement this delegate method:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didLongPressAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    let marker = GMSMarker(position: coordinate)
    // marker.isDraggable = true
    // marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
    marker.map = mapView
    // marker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImage(with: UIColor.blue)
}
```

The commented-out lines are optional as they are just setting custom attributes of the marker. There are lots more that you can customize.

Also, if you haven't done so already, add `GMSMapViewDelegate` to your view controller class' declaration:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate {
```

and assign `self` to the `delegate` property:

```
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 0, longitude: 0, zoom: 3)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    view = mapView

    mapView.delegate = self // add this line!
```

Alternatively, you can add markers when other events happen. For example, you can add a marker when the user taps on a `UIBarBUttonItem` or a `UIButton`. It's all up to you! But the process of adding a button is basically these two lines:

```
let marker = GMSMarker(position: coordinate)
marker.map = mapView 
// mapView is the map that you want to add the marker to. If you are doing this outside a delegate method, use self.view
```

You can also consider adding the markers to a collection so you can modify them later.

Comment: If you think my answer answers your question please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark! @lust